# Apache Spark Maven POM errors

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am trying out Apache Spark and have a little problem that I am stuck with. I have this [JavaSparkHiveExample.java](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/hive/JavaSparkHiveExample.java) example from the Apache Spark Github together with a [pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/pom.xml) that I have created as a Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA.

I am able to run other Spark examples (using another simpler POM) but [this one](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/pom.xml) is giving me the following errors:

[image]

- Scala is installed in Idea

I am new with Maven and would therefore appreciate some things I could try in order to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with the value of $project.version. It is referring to your project' version (2.3.0-snapshot). There isn't any maven dependency with this version in Maven central repository, hence you are facing this issue. Instead of using the project version, you can add a new property like this and refer it for all dependency version

```
<properties>
 <spark.version>1.6.2</spark.version>
</properties>
```

and then use it in the dependency

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Make sure the version you are using is available in maven repository
https://mvnrepository.com/
[image]